# Restricting Kubernetes resources based on RBAC while listing across all namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'd like to list a specific resource (e.g. `pod`) across all namespaces in a Kubernetes cluster, but to have the result contain only resources permitted by [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

For example, assume I grant permissions for a certain service account to perform all operations on all `pod`s in 2 namespaces `ns1` and `ns2`. These permissions include the ability to `list` `pods`. I can do this using RBAC.

Then I'd like to perform the equivalent of:

```sh
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

... but get only the `pod`s in namespaces `ns1` and `ns2`.

If I grant permissions to `list` all `pod`s across all namespaces, I get more information than I'd like. And even if that were acceptable, I'd then have to filter the results based on other criteria (e.g. resources to which I granted `get` access).

**Note:** I'd like the solution to be based solely on RBAC, as I have little control over the query, since I'm using a [graphql wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-to-graphql) that performs the query programmatically for me and it does it across **all namespaces**.

Comment: Not sure how it can be done solely with RBAC. However, if you could translate this to your tool, this may help.`for ns in $(kubectl get ns -ojsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}');do kubectl get pod -n $ns  2>/dev/null ;done`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not really possible.

To restrict user access to specific namespace, you would have to create Role and RoleBinding for that namespace.
`--all-namespaces` flag requires ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding to work.
Since RBAC permissions are additive, setting ClusterRole would "overwrite" any perivilege restrictions from Role and RoleBinding.

If a user should only have access to a single namespace he cannot be assigned to a ClusterRole.

Your best bet is to change how graphql wrapper executes the query.